# Wildcard query on a JSON column

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table name "books" and it has a JSON column called name. In that JSON will store 3 key value pairs.

example JSON:

```
{"TAMIL": "", "ENGLISH": "7 Habbits", "SINHALA": ""}
```

I'm trying to search on that json according to ENGLISH key's value as a Wildcard query as bellow. But it doesn't return a values. Any suggestion ?

```
SELECT * FROM test.books WHERE JSON_SEARCH(name, 'all',  '"ENGLISH":"%a%"')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON_EXTRACT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.ENGLISH") LIKE '%a%';
```

In MySQL 5.7.9 and later, the -> operator serves as an alias for the JSON_EXTRACT()

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE name->"$.ENGLISH" LIKE '%a%';
```

This filter work also for case where key 'ENGLISH' not exists. Fiddle: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=6826c6162a249b71fbd21986cbb7581b&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.books 
WHERE name->>"$.ENGLISH" LIKE '%a%';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f51357aa0b21ed1f61f0e517aa50731)